# How to vertically align radio buttons

Tags: radio-button, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h2>Transfer Options:</h2>
    <div class="row  well well-sm">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div id="sendTypeRadio" class="btn-group-vertical" >
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <input id="radioEmail" type="radio" name="sendType" value="email" disabled>Email
          </span>
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <input id="radioAttachments" type="radio" name="sendType" value="attachments" disabled>Attachments
          </span>
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <input id="radioBoth" type="radio" name="sendType" value="both" disabled>Email and attachments
          </span>
        </div><!-- /input-group -->
      </div><!-- /.col-xs-6 -->
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is the buttons are all next to each other on the x-axis. I have been changing things for a day. Moving it out of the row tag and back in, removing almost all the formatting and such. What I want to maintain is the input-group-addon styling, but I want each button on a new row. I've searched and found nothing, any clues?

Comment: This may sound silly, but have you tried to add <br> between the spans?

Comment: Then why don’t you just simply display the spans as `block` …?

Comment: And btw., you should write _better_ HTML. Instead of meaningless spans, using `label`s would be in order …

Comment: I am writing in the bootsrap style, you're supposed to use spans for the component I'm using. This question is specific to bootstrap, which has demands slightly different than plain jane html.

Answer (score 0):

In asking my question I came up with a really crappy answer:

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
<h2>Transfer Options:</h2>
<div class="row  well well-sm">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div id="sendTypeRadio" class="btn-group-vertical" >
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-2">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <input id="radioEmail" type="radio" name="sendType" value="email" disabled>Email
      </span>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-2">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <input id="radioAttachments" type="radio" name="sendType" value="attachments" disabled>Attachments
      </span>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-2">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <input id="radioBoth" type="radio" name="sendType" value="both" disabled>Email and attachments
      </span>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div><!-- /.col-xs-6 -->
</div>
```

This gives me each item on a new row but absolutely ruins the styling of [Bootstrap radio buttons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-checkboxes-radios)